# iphone simulator always gives status 200 from ajax request

Tags: jquery, ios, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cordova

When I run this ajax request on my browser and I put wrong information it gives me the status 0 and fails the ajax. But, when I run this on a simulator even if I leave the login information empty, it always returns status 200. How can I get it to print the right status code?

I'm using phonegap and ruby on rails (for the back end)

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in',
          data:{ user: { 

               email: e, 
               password: p
           } },
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
              alert(jqXHR.status);

          },
          error: function(jqXHR, data, errorThrown){
              alert(jqXHR.status);
}

    });
```

Comment: Why 0 instead of, say, 400? (not sure if that has anything to do with the behavior though.)

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX calls are probably getting cached, add this to your call after the `type` param:

```
cache: false,
```

Comment: It still returns the status code 200 on the phone simulator

Comment: Sorry, should have read closer. Are you trying to call `localhost` from a device? This will not work. You need to call and actual address or IP address

Comment: I have this application on actual address as well, I just tested it on the actual address. That doesn't seem to be the issue.